# Does AppleReceipt.inAppPurchaseReceipts contain info for subscriptions as well?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase, subscription

I'm trying to get info about my subscription expiration date and validation,
but my Apple In App receipts is empty, is it because subscriptions are not considered in app purchase?

```
byte[] receiptData = Convert.FromBase64String(appleConfig.appReceipt);
AppleValidator validator = new AppleValidator(AppleTangle.Data());
AppleReceipt localAppleReceipt = validator.Validate(receiptData);
receipts = localAppleReceipt.inAppPurchaseReceipts
receipt[0].subscriptionExpirationDate...
```

Do I need to use Subscription Manager `SubscriptionInfo.IsExpired()` instead of validate?